# Triangulation of a 3-sphere

Tags: manifolds, triangulation, compact-manifolds

If one wants to generate a Simplicial complex of the topology of the 3-sphere, one can just take the boundary of a 5-cell, 16-cell or 600-cell. The curvature is concentrated on the edges meeting the tetrahedrons.
Is there a way to further triangulate the tetrahedrons and redistribute the curvature uniformly on the new edges? Maybe there is a standard way to do such things?
Maybe also for the triangulation of other (compact) 3-manifolds?